# Is it possible to get YQL to return multiple JSON results from a site in a single request?

Tags: json, join, yql

I'm currently using this YQL (Yahoo Query Language) query to convert the JSON from a site to JSONP:

```
select * from json where url="http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/ABC?fmt=JSON"
```

`ABC` is the parameter.

So I know YQL is designed to be similar to SQL and I think has some feature that lets you do joins, but I'm not sure if it would be possible to use these features to combine several queries to this airportcode site into a single request. (The site doesn't support this and the site's owner hasn't replied to my email query.)

Basically I want a YQL query that will get not just results for `ABC` but for `ABC`, `XYZ`, `FOO`, in one call. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also make good use of the `uritemplate` table to convert the airport codes into a group of URLs which can then be fed to the `json` table.

**Airport Codes to URLs**

The `uritemplate` table takes a "template" and any number of values to populate that template with. (See also, [**URI Template**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gregorio-uritemplate-03) draft).

In this case the needs are simple, just inject the airport code into the path at the appropriate place.

```
select * from uritemplate where
template="http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/{airport}?fmt=JSON"
and airport in ("SFO", "LAX", "LHR")
```

<sup>([Try this query in the YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/uAxKj))</sup>

This gives the following result (`diagnostics` information removed for simplicity).

[image: result of query]

**Getting JSON results from these URLs**

Now that we have a list of URLs, it is simple enough to use the `json` table to retrieve the JSON for each of them by using a [**sub-select**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/joins.html).  In fact we already used a sub-select above, recognisable by the `in (…)` syntax.

```
select * from json where url in (
    select url from uritemplate 
    where template="http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/{airport}?fmt=JSON" 
    and airport in ("SFO", "LAX", "LHR")
)
```

<sup>([Try this query in the YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/REMzx))</sup>

The result this time looks like.

[image: query result]

**Easy querying**

I am a big fan of YQL's [**query aliases**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_url.html#yql-query-aliases) (and the associated **variable substitution** like `@var`) which can provide neat endpoints for you to access without the need to embed the YQL query into the URL. The link above details how to create them, and the end result is that you could have a YQL query such as the one below.

```
select * from json where url in (
    select url from uritemplate where 
    template="http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/{airport}?fmt=JSON" 
    and airport in (@ap)
)
```

With a query alias (I've called it `airports`) the query can be accessible via a URL like the one below, and have the ability to easily change or add more/fewer airport codes easily.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/peter/airports?ap=SFO&ap=LHR&ap=BOB
```

<sup>([Go there](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/peter/airports?ap=SFO&ap=LHR&ap=BOB). Note: I might delete this alias without notice.)</sup>

Reading:

- [`desc uritemplate` query](http://y.ahoo.it/x0XsI)
- [URI Template draft spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gregorio-uritemplate-03)
- [YQL sub-selects](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/joins.html)

Comment: No it's not normal, looks like you're Doing It Wrong™.  If you haven't solved it yet, show us what you're doing to get that result structure.

Answer (score 1):

**YES!**

And it doesn't use anything complicated like `join`, `query.multi`, or `execute`. After hunting around for such options I finally found it's much simpler than that requiring only `or` and repeated use of `url=`, one for each parameter:

```
select * from json where url="http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/LAX?fmt=JSON"
  or url="http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/SFO?fmt=JSON"
  or url="http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/LHR?fmt=JSON"
```

I'd like to hear if there's a neater way to do it without the repetitive similar URLs.